# More than one select option per line

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on some form and trying to get more than one select option per line as it is on the screnshoot above:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIwKy.png

Is it even possible to create something like this? I try to wrap select option in span, put them inline and some others methods but sadly none of them works correctly and items are still listed in block.

My code is simple right now:

```
<select class="form-control w-100 ml-2" id="godzina">
<option></option>
<option>16:00</option>                                                                              
<option>16:30</option>
<option>17:00</option>                                            
<option>17:30</option>
</select>
```

I am using Bootstrap 4. Is there any solution to made it this way, or I should use for example radio inputs?

//edit: Only one options is allowed to select.

Comment: _“or I should use for example radio inputs?”_ - yes, you should. (How to show clickable text labels instead of the actual radio button elements - easy to research.)

Comment: with a little bit js it should be possible like there [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m6qdhn87/)

Comment: @theoretisch thank you, your solution is actually working, with some changes I managed to do what I wanna. Simple and clean solution :)